# Centos7 PXE Network Install with Kickstart Script - How to copy across folders / files from network during install?

Tags: centos, centos7, ftp, pxe-boot, kickstart

I have a PXE server for network installations (configured similar to, e.g. https://www.linuxtechi.com/configure-pxe-installation-server-centos-7/) and am using a Kickstart script to automatically implement many settings. The CentOS image is stored on the PXE server and accessed via FTP (location on server: `/var/ftp/pub`)

Is it possible for the kickstart script to copy across files from the PXE server so they are available on the client's hard-drive when the install is finished?

i.e. I have a folder called `foo` on the server: `/var/ftp/pub/foo`. How can I copy across this so that the freshly installed client has these files at e.g. `/home/foo` please?

I've seen numerous questions asking this already for DVD / USB installs, but my question concerns network installations so I don't think the scripts used for DVD installs will work.

Thanks

Comment: In theory you can use most of the  tools installed on your systems in the post section of a kickstart. (You may need to use ip-addresses rather than hostnames (when you run in a chroot)) Consider checking out content from a git repository, running curl, rsync or simply mount a nfs export and copy the file tree you need. - I prefer to **only do the minimal in the kickstart to enroll the newly installed system in our configuration management system** and then after the system boots normally for the first time all logic and settings are applied from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can copy files during Kickstart.

Depending on when you copy the files in Kickstart, you may or may not be in a chroot environment. Your copy target might need to use the filesystem under `/mnt/sysimage`.

Use the virtual console during install and play around inside the Anaconda environment. Inspect `mount` to see how your remote FTP is mounted so you can get the source for the copy. Insert a `sleep` or similar in various stages of Kickstart so you can get the time you need in each.

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion. How do I access the virtual console though please?

Comment: CTRL + ALT + F1 through F7 are each different virtual consoles with different purpose. You can read more about it here. https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/installation_guide/sect-consoles-logs-during-installation-x86#sect-installation-consoles-x86